# resource is not passed - node js

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm trying to forward created resource (http) by callback to print result on web page using it

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var fs = require ('fs');
var Path = require('path');


function LookDirs(server,port,callback){
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('<html><head><title>Simple Server</title></head>');
    res.write('<body> Test1');
    callback('..', res);
    res.end('\n</body</html>');
  }).listen(port);
};



function ViewContent(dirPath){
  fs.readdir(dirPath, function(err, entries){
    for (var idx in entries){
      var fullPath = Path.join(dirPath, entries[idx]);
      (function(fullPath){
            console.log(fullPath,idx);
            res.write('abc');
        })(fullPath);
      }
    })
}

LookDirs("Test 234", "1337", ViewContent);
```

And I keep getting

```
        res.write('abc');
        ^
```

ReferenceError: res is not defined

I was sure that I have passed that resource during callback..

Answer (score 0):

You can not access res from ViewContent. 
This (req, res) responses from createServer stand for request and response. Here you can see more about it: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

```
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    // magic happens here!
});
```

Also you can not run callbacks on createServer prototype, but you can run on the listen method though.

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var Path = require('path');


function LookDirs(server, port, callback) {
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write('<html><head><title>Simple Server</title></head>');
        res.write('<body> Test1');
        res.end('\n</body</html>');
    }).listen(port, callback("./"));
};

function ViewContent(dirPath) {
    fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, entries) {
        for (var idx in entries) {
            var fullPath = Path.join(dirPath, entries[idx]);
            // I can not access res from here, it has sent already.
            console.log(fullPath)
        }
    })
}

LookDirs("Test 234", "1337", ViewContent);
```